# data not saving in mongo db database only generate id in collection

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I am new in nodejs, mongoose, express, i am trying to create Rest API.
when i hit post method in postman only i get id

below is my code:

1. this is server file where i made server and creating end point here please see my code, if i am wrong any where

```
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
//const userRouter = require('./src/routes/user');
const User = require('./src/models/user');

require('./src/db/db');
//require('./src/controler/user.controler');
const app = express();
const PORT = process.env.port || 4000

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

//app.post('/app', userRouter);
app.post('/user', (req , res)=> {
    const newUser = new User(req.body);

    newUser.save().then((result)=>{
        console.log(result)
    }).catch((err)=>{
        console.log(err)
    })

    res.send(newUser);
})


app.listen(PORT, (err)=> {
    if(!err) {
        console.log('Server is listening on port' + " " + PORT );
    }
});
```

2. Schema file

```
const UserSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
        type: String
    },
    age: {
        type: Number
    }
})

const User  = mongoose.model('Alluser', UserSchema);
module.exports = User
```

Comment: make sure that `req.body` inside your `/user` route handler function contains `name` and `age` properties

Comment: Hi ,@Yousaf  I am making post request from postman and giving value of name an d age property there.

Comment: try to log `req.body.name` and `req.body.age` on the console and check if correct values get printed

Comment: @Yousaf : only id generated, id is coming in console.
but when i put static value of name and age like this:
``` const newUser = new User({
        name: 'Mukesh',
        age: 24
    });

then it's saving in db

Comment: i am not asking to log user document. Just console log `req.body.name` and `req.body.age` and make sure the values you pass from postman are printed on the console. If that's not the case, your request body is not being parsed correctly

Comment: Bu sure that in Postman, body tab you choose first raw option, and then the JSON option in the right dropdown. And send a request body like this: { "name": "Mukesh", "age": 24 }. And remove res.send(newUser);  line, and put this line in the then block  
    res.send(result);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check how you are sending your values via postman.
You should send data in **application/json format** via postman.

> try { name: 'Mukesh', age: 24 } with application/json header via postman.

Comment: I was making request as text in postman, i changed as JSON and it's working. Thanks Cheers!!

Comment: Yes that was the only problem :)

Comment: after taking long time to figure this out, your answer solve my issue. Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes what cause this type of error its when you have not included express middleware like this in your code.

```
app.use(express.json())
```